# Grepping account names (read from a file) from a set of compressed files

Tags: shell-script, grep, io-redirection, gzip

This script:

```
while read ACCT ; do
echo $ACCT
zgrep -h ^$ACCT datafile.0[2-3]2015.gz >>/tmp/$ACCT.txt
done < /account_list.txt
```

I get no redirected output file
When I remove `'>>/tmp/$ACCT.txt'`, the output goes to stdout, which is expected.
I'm not understanding why, in this example, I get no redirected output.
I also tried, instead of zgrep...

```
zcat datafile.0[2-3]2015.gz|grep ^$ACCT>>/tmp/$ACCT.txt...
```

but this yields no output.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to debug a piece of code without knowing what data goes into it.  I will therefore refrain from speculating about what could possibly be wrong with your code apart from saying that `^$ACCT` should probably be double quoted, as should all other occurrences of `$ACCT`.

---

Rather than calling `zgrep` once for each line in `account_list.txt` (uncompresing those data files as many times as there are lines in that file), read the accounts into an array in `awk` and do the processing in a single pass:

```
awk 'NR==FNR { acct[$1]; next }
     $1 in acct { file="/tmp/" $1 ".txt"; print >>file; close(file) }' \
    account_list.txt <( zcat datafile.0[2-3]2015.gz )
```

This assumes `bash` or some other shell that understands process substitutions. It also assumes that the list of accounts contain the account name in the first column and that the data files also contains the account name in the first column (you haven't actually shown what these files look like, so I can't say whether this would work or not).

The first `awk` block is only executed for the first file, `account_list.txt`, and will create an associative array, `acct`, with the account names to extract as the keys.

The second block is only executed over the lines of the extracted data files, and if the first field corresponds to a key in `acct`, then that line is printed to an appropriately named file.

Comment: Bash doesn’t care about the quotes, I’ve verified that. The data set is a simple list, one string per line.

Comment: When I remove the ‘>>/$ACCT.txt’, I get the desired output to stdout, which is expected.

Comment: @MarkSJames What is the value of `$ACCT`?With some values of `$ACCT` `bash` will _definitely_ care about the quotes. I can't say anything constructive unless I know what the data looks like.

Comment: A txt file with 30 lines, for example, each containing a string like ‘123456789’. Quotes are mine, not part of the strings.

Comment: The ‘echo’ command is displaying a correct value for $ACCT. And using bash -x shows a correct value also.

Comment: I do see the validity of using ‘awk’, hadn’t considered the overhead. Thx

Comment: So, my account_list.txt looks like:

Comment: Every time I hit ‘return’ on my iPad, it sends the comment so it’s difficult to illustrate effectively. Sry

Comment: @MarkSJames Please edit your question instead of adding further information in comments (where it may be missed by readers).

Comment: After some trial/error, the only solution was to use 'tee'. Still curious why the seeming straightforward code wouldn't work, but at least there was a solution, as always.

Comment: @MarkSJames It was probably due to a space in `$ACCT`.  Double quoting the variable would have prevented the issue.